# Can you explain to me this part of a warping method (Using OpenCV, C++ and Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm learning OpenCV and I'm working on a project to warp a certain region of an image (the face). Here is the code :

```
            Mat input = imread("Lena.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            Mat out;
            cvtColor(input,input,CV_BGR2GRAY);
            double xo, yo;
            input.convertTo(input, CV_32FC1);
            copyMakeBorder(input, input, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0);

            int height = input.rows;
            int width = input.cols;
            int PI =3.141592;

            out = Mat(height, width, input.type());


            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
                for(int i =0; i < width; i++){
                    xo = (8.0 * sin(2.0 * PI * j / 128.0));
                    yo = (8.0 * sin(2.0 * PI * i / 128.0));
                    out.at<float>(j,i) = (float)input.at<float>(((int)(j+yo+height)%height),((int)(i+xo+width)%width));

                    int ix = min(width-1, max(0, (int) (i + xo)));
                    int iy = min(height-1, max(0, (int) (j + yo)));
                    out.at<float>(j,i) = (float)input.at<float>(iy,ix);
                }
            }
            normalize(out, out,0,255,NORM_MINMAX,CV_8UC1);
```

Here is what it looks like :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0yoc.jpg

The problem is, i'm pretty new to OpenCV so i don't understand how the code works (The part about the modification itself). I'd like to understand it to be able to apply it better like only on the chin to make a "fat effect" or something like that for example.

Thanks

Comment: Think about what this line does `out.at<float>(j,i) = (float)input.at<float>(((int)(j+yo+height)%height),((int)(i+xo+width)%width));`

Comment: I think I understand this part in fact, we replace the <!-- (j,i) --> pixel in "out" by the (((int)(j+yo+height)%height),((int)(i+xo+width)%width)) pixel in "input", but i don't get why this will cause the modification we see

Comment: x0 and y0 are offsets generated by `(8.0 * sin(2.0 * PI * j / 128.0))`

Comment: The effect is a sine wave shift of both x and y.

Comment: So let's say i would like to do some kind of a mirror effect, i could apply this sine wave to the right side of the face, then apply a cos wave to the left side ? (Do i just need to replace the "sin" in xo = (8.0 * sin(2.0 * PI * j / 128.0)); by "cos" ?

Comment: Once you say "left and right side" you imply not displacement by a (row wise constant) offset but you imply other forms of manipulation such as stretching.

Comment: I've tried to do that, and i got this http://imgur.com/m8HkXzn but as you can see, there is no mirror effect in the middle, it looks like the sine and cosine are not in phase

Answer (score 2):

```
xo = (8.0 * sin(2.0 * PI * j / 128.0));
yo = (8.0 * sin(2.0 * PI * i / 128.0));
```

`xo` and `yo` are offsets.  They vary sinusoidally with a period of `128` pixels and an amplitude of `8` pixels with the `i` and `j` coordinate of the output.  `xo` is a function of `j` and `yo` is a function of `i`.

```
out.at<float>(j,i) = (float)input.at<float>(((int)(j+yo+height)%height),((int)(i+xo+width)%width));
```

this line appears to do nothing, because we overwrite it shortly.  I do not know why it exists.  It appears to do "wrap around" the edges?  Maybe it is left over from an earlier version of the algorithm.

```
int ix = min(width-1, max(0, (int) (i + xo)));
int iy = min(height-1, max(0, (int) (j + yo)));
```

`ix` and `iy` are clamped versions of `i+xo` and `j+yo`.  Note that `xo` is a function of `j` and is added to `i`, so the value of `ix` for a fixed `i` goes up and down as `j` changes.  This is the horizontal wave effect.

The equivalent happens with `iy` waving as `i` changes.

```
out.at<float>(j,i) = (float)input.at<float>(iy,ix);
```

here we sample and set our output.  The pixel is read from the input at some offset.  Presumably the `input.at<float>` function has some kind of interpolation for smooth values at fractional input.

The above code will probably generate artifacts if the local compression factor gets too large, but the pair of sin waves generates a distortion that is near unity in compression (just twisting/sheering).

Doing this kind of operation only on part of the *output* image is somewhat easy if someone else finds the region.  You'd scale the amplitude factor smoothly based on some mask (you may have to fuzz the mask to make the mask smooth).  Inverting the mask (so that the pixels that "would come from" some part of the input image) is harder.  Detecting where the face is is harder again.  Making it look "professional" would be another step and require lots of tweaking of the preliminary results.

All of them are going to be significantly harder than what this algorithm does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Regarding this line : out.at<float>(j,i) = (float)input.at<float>(((int)(j+yo+height)%height),((int)(i+xo+width)%width));   It was the only one in the first version of the algorithm i found here but the "black zone" due to the warping were replaced by the original image (Without warping) so the user add the two lines you wrote below to correct that, and just display black. The face detection is already done, i was just wondering why i need to work in gray to do this warping ?

Comment: @AdrienB I see no good reason why grayscale is needed to do warping.  The image was loaded as greyscale.  I don't know the openCV library enough to see if there are other things that would need changing: I would advise you to change it to non-greyscale and see what happens.  And try deleting that first line with `out.at<float>(j,i)=...`, it probably just wastes time.

Comment: I deleted the line and you were right it worked. I tried to work in RGB instead of gray but it doesn't work, i don't know why but it seems that i need to work in greyscale.

Comment: @AdrienB You are not using any "only grayscale" functions, you may work with RGB images if you wanted, but you will need to remember that you have 3 channels and not 1, and do the appropriate changes...

Comment: I'v tried to replace it with "out.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[0] = (float)input.at<Vec3b>(iy,ix)[0];" (3 times for [0],[1] and [2]) but it doesn't work, it replace my face with a grey square (Instead of a greyscaled warped face)